# Why not always use Inf instead of Lazy in Idris?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, idris, codata

I find that `Lazy` and `Inf` is very close:

> Lazy and Inf are closely related (in fact, the underlying
>   implementation uses the same type). The only difference in practice is
>   in totality checking, where Lazy is erased (i.e. terms are checked for
>   termination normally, ignoring laziness annotations), and Inf uses a
>   productivity checker, where any use of Delay must be constructor
>   guarded.

As described [above](https://www.idris-lang.org/idris-0-9-12-released/), the underlying implementation of `Lazy` and `Inf` is the same one, the only difference is about totality checking.

I think always use `Inf` seems much more natural, which is more close to the lazy we used in Haskell, and wondering what is the scene in production which we must use `Lazy` -- which always do a deep totality checking?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think `Inf` is for codata and `Lazy` is for data. Due to totality the lazy data should produce the same result as strict data, just with a different evaluation order and hence performance profile.

Comment: It seems that Lazy is not very useful as a Type, since the evaluation strategy doesn't need to be part of the type signature (and it is also impossible)

Comment: This is what I've been thinking as well. Lazy does the same thing.